# Need to remove the path from the output of a grep but not the file

Tags: shell, cron, grep, output

I have a script that works great but in that script I am using grep to extract two lines

```
grep -e "string1" -e "string" my_fliles* >> //destination
```

The output of that looks good

```
filename1 string1
filename1 string2
filename2 string1
filename2 string2
filename3 string1
filename3 string2
```

That is the desired effect but in order to get it to work in a cron job I have to specify the full path to my_files

```
grep -e "string1" -e "string" /home/username/scriptfolder/logs/my_fliles* >> //destination
```

That creates output like

```
/home/username/scriptfolder/logs/filename1 string1
/home/username/scriptfolder/logs/filename1 string2
/home/username/scriptfolder/logs/filename2 string1
/home/username/scriptfolder/logs/filename2 string2
/home/username/scriptfolder/logs/filename3 string1
/home/username/scriptfolder/logs/filename3 string2
```

I want the filenames and the string outputs but not the path.
I tried removing the path and specifying the path in the script with

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/username/scriptfolder/logs/
```

but that did not work.
anny suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -e "string1" -e "string" ./my_fliles* | 
awk -F " " '{ n = split($1,RES,"/"); OUT=RES[n];
for( i=2; i<=NF; i++) { OUT=OUT" "$i } print OUT;}'
```

In the `grep` results, the path and string are separated by a `' '` (space)

```
/home/username/scriptfolder/logs/filename1 string1
```

You can use the `-F` flag to set the field separator used by `awk`, the default separator is space.
This splits the input into `$1, $2, . . . , $NF` fields.

`awk` has a predefined function `split`.

```
n = split( String, A, [Ere] )
```

This function splits the string specified by the `String` parameter into array elements `A[1], A[2], . . ., A[n]`, and returns the value
of the `n` variable. The separation is done with the extended regular expression specified by the `Ere` parameter or with
the current field separator (the `FS` special variable) if the `Ere` parameter is not given. The elements in the A array are
created with string values, unless context indicates a particular element should also have a numeric value.

`for( i=2; i<=NF; i++) { OUT=OUT" "$i }` will concatenate the original input fields into the variable OUT separated by space. This is to ensure that we do not miss any fields due to spaces in the searched string **string1** or **string2**. Note that the loop started with `i=2`

The final output will look like below:

```
filename1 string1
filename1 string2
filename2 string1
```

Comment: thanks for resolution that works, and also the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

`PATH` is the search paths to find an executable, not for regular files, so it won't work. Try this in your crontab command:

```
cd /home/username/scriptfolder/logs; grep -e "string1" -e "string" my_fliles* >> //destination
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a way to suppress the path if you do `grep` outside the directory. You can however, use `awk` to strip the path. Something like:

```
awk -F/ '{print $NF}' <(grep -e "string1" -e "string" /home/username/scriptfolder/logs/my_fliles*) > destination
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `grep -e "string1" -e "string" ./my_fliles* >> //destination` manually  then 
make a script with these two lines and run that script

```
cd /home/username/scriptfolder/logs/
grep -e "string1" -e "string" ./my_fliles* >> //destination
```

if `grep -e "string1" -e "string" ./my_fliles* >> //destination` is a part of script  then add

`cd /home/username/scriptfolder/logs/`
this line before

`grep -e "string1" -e "string" ./my_fliles* >> //destination`

Comment: best: use pushd, popd rather than cd